# Intersecting Secants Theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, tangent-line

Let the point $A$ lie on the exterior of the circle $k(R).$ From $A$ are drawn the tangents $AB$ and $AC$ to $k.$ The triangle $ABC$ is еquilateral. Find the side of $\triangle ABC$.

> Answer: $R\sqrt{3}.$

[image]
I am not sure how to approach the problem. We should use the Intersecting Chords Theorem. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: The triangle $BOC$ is isosceles and the base angles are  30 degrees.

Comment: Another way: for $ABOC$ the sum of angles is $360^\circ$, but $\angle B=\angle C=90^\circ$, so $\angle BOC=180^\circ -\angle CAB=120^\circ$, then apply the cosine rule for $\triangle BOC$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Join $O$ and $A$. $OA$ bisects $\angle ABC$ and so $\angle OAB=30^\circ$. What is $\tan\angle OAB$?

Comment: Hints should be given in comments first. Don't simply post hints in answers just for votes.

Comment: @Doubtnut The OP specifically asked for a hint, so what’s wrong with posting it as an answer?

Comment: Comments are used for hints.

Comment: @Doubtnut Not necessarily. I see many people post hints as answers.

Comment: It is not necessary that you should copy the same. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22123/is-it-wrong-to-answer-a-question-that-others-are-discussing-in-the-comments)

Comment: @Doubtnut It is necessary that I do what I must to enjoy my experience on this site. The link you shared is irrelevant in this discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108879/discussion-between-doubtnut-and-tavish).